# Harmonic functions are analytic

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $B_1\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be the unitary ball centered in the origin, and let $u$ be an harmonic function in $B_1$, i.e.
$$
-\Delta u = 0 \,\,\,\,\, \mbox{in}\,\,\, B_1.
$$
How can i prove that $u$ is analytic?
Moreover, how can be proved this results using some estimates on the high order derivative? I know that it must be a classic result, also in several variables, but i cannot find a good reference.

Comment: Try this: http://www.dma.im.ufrj.br/~mcabral/textos/edp/harmonic-analytic.pdf

Comment: @user209663 This seems to assume a priori that $u$ is smooth. Still, it is probably what Gio712 was looking for.

Comment: Yes, i'm assuming that $u$ is smooth. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A typical approach would be the same as for proving that holomorphic functions are analytic. That is, represent $u$ in terms of its boundary values on some ball contained in the domain of $u$ (the Poisson formula does that). The Poisson kernel is real-analytic, since it is basically $(r^2-|x|^2)/|\zeta-x|^2$ where both numerator and denominator are polynomials of $x$ (the point $\zeta$ is a boundary point, $|\zeta|=r$). The power series converges when $|x|<r$, hence it can be integrated term by term on compact subsets of this ball. This gives a power series representation of $u$.